# SMTP Excel corrupted attachment files

Tags: vb6, smtp, excel-2003

I've created a VB6 application from which I wish to send an SMTP email. The email is sent and received fine but when attaching an Excel 2003 file, whilst this is received okay, when trying to open it file becomes corrupt... I've also tried saving the attachment and then opening it but the problem persists.  Thank you for any assistance...

Comment: You're most likely corrupting the file when you encode it (if you are at all). We'll have to see some code, network transfer logs before we can help much further though. Are any other file types cotrrupt (I expect any non text file)

Comment: Thanks Deanna - much appreciate your kind assistance. To confirm, I'm not encoding the file but I will take your advice and try to send a basic text document to see if this becomes corrupt and let you know the outcome.  Thank you - Chris

Answer (score 0):

The attachment data must be encoded. Not all mail servers and clients are 8-bit safe.
Base64 is the most common encoding method.

Comment: Thank you Deanna - can you explain how BASE64 encoding is carried out please.

Comment: The relevant RFC is http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt. There is a bit more info and a sample at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323489